# What is a term for a genre that is not sci-fi or fantasy?

Tags: word-choice

I need a term to distinguish movies such as *Die Hard* or *Taken* from the likes of *The Lord of the Rings* or *Minority Report*. Broadly speaking, they are all action movies. But what do I say when I want to exclude genres like sci-fi, fantasy and superhero? What would I call a movie set in the real world with human characters, one which doesn’t include mythical or superhuman characters or settings?

Comment: An *action* movie, maybe a *thriller*. Perhaps *gritty*.

Comment: In SF or fantasy circles, such movies are referred to as _mainstream_. But I'm not sure if that is a specific enough term.

Comment: Gritty doesn't sound like a genre, and thriller is a totally different thing which doesn't necessarily exclude sci-fi (Minority Report, Total Recall, Twelve Monkeys... I could go on).

**Mainstream** sounds better to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Head on over to your local video store, and you'll see the typical groupings for movie genres. Generally, though, these types of movies belong in the Action genre.

Many movies cross over the boundaries of genre. [Taken](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0936501/), for example, is classed as Action/Crime/Thriller. [Die Hard](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095016/) is classed as Action/Thriller. [Minority Report](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0181689/) is classed as Action/Mystery/Sci-Fi. [LOTR](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120737/) is Action/Adventure/Fantasy. Given the broad sweep of genres covering Action, I would suggest non-Sci-Fi Action.

For some great definitions of movie genres and sub-genres, you should check out [filmsite.org](http://www.filmsite.org/). They have a great listing of [genres](http://www.filmsite.org/genres.html), [sub-genres](http://www.filmsite.org/subgenres.html) and [hybrids](http://www.filmsite.org/subgenres2.html).

Comment: Good answer because it highlights the fact that genres aren't mutually exclusive. They're also vague and subjective. Given the potential for overlap between (I think) any pair or more of genres, if you want to be sure to exclude genres from a list then you probably need to be explicit about it. But rather than "non sci-fi action", in order to discount fantasy/superhero as well, I'd suggest something like "real world action".